# should I post an answer to a slightly old question that already has some good answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, answers-in-comments

to be more specific, should I post an answer to a question if I like at least one of the answers it already has, but I believe it is missing something that I myself could add, or should I just add said thing via a comment?

Comment: related: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/5838/23970, specifically point #2 in SSD's answer. (Though it comes at your issue obliquely.)

Comment: see also the answers and discussions here: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3571/23970

Comment: ok, so far the answer I have and the comments (and the links in said comments) are pretty helpful, but they also leave the argument sort of balanced either way. not necessarily a bad thing but I think I will wait a day or two to decide what to do. (the question I am talking about certainly isn't fresh enough to effect the decision anyway) should I link the question I mean or is it not as helpful as more general information?

Comment: yeah, there's not necessarily a "right" or "wrong" way to handle it. I recently had a similar-sounding experience with [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71888/23970). I posted an answer, another posted an opposing answer. I actually came around to seeing the reasonableness of the opposing answer, urged some improvements to it (in comments), and waited a few days. When the second user didn't make any of those improvements I went ahead and posted the second of my answers. In the end voters have the arguments *I* think are worth considering, and the other user had a "fair chance."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Two approaches, both valid:

#### 1. Leave a comment on the answer you like.

Suggest the improvement. "Favorite" the question so it's easy for you to come back and check on later. *Be prepared for the eventuality that the author may disagree, or may never respond.*

#### 2. Post your own answer.

If you think your additional content really adds something, the only way to guarantee its visibility is to post your own answer. In this situation be sure to point out how much of your answer is derivative of any others' work, and how your original contribution really makes yours the best answer. Then let the (long-term) voting sort it out.

Your (presumably) better answer may never overcome the benefit of early-posting that the other answers received. But cream will rise, and wise future readers will look further than just the accepted answer.